# Implementing LinkedList in C

Tags: c

I implemented a linked list for my school assignment but when I try to print out value of a node, the first node always get printed with memory address and I can't figure out why it's happening.

I tried debugging and as I assign tail of list to the new node, the value of the node gets printed out as memory address.

Why is this happening?

```
int AppendLinkedList(LinkedListPtr list, int value) {
    LinkedListNodePtr newNode = CreateLinkedListNode(value);
    if (list->head == NULL) {
        list->head = newNode;
        list->tail = newNode;
        
        return 0;
    }
    LinkedListNodePtr tailCopy = list->tail;
    newNode->prev = tailCopy;
    tailCopy->next = newNode;
    list->tail = newNode;
    return 0;
}

LinkedListNode *CreateLinkedListNode(int data) {
    LinkedListNodePtr newNode;
    newNode = (LinkedListNodePtr)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListNode));
    newNode->data = data;
    printf("%d\n", data);
    return newNode;
}

int main() {
    LinkedListPtr list = CreateLinkedList();
    int data = 5;
    AppendLinkedList(list, data);
}

typedef struct ll_node {
    int           data;       // Data this node holds 
    struct ll_node *next;     // next node in list, or NULL
    struct ll_node *prev;     // prev node in list, or NULL
} LinkedListNode, *LinkedListNodePtr;

typedef struct ll_head {
    uint64_t          num_elements;  //  # elements in the list
    LinkedListNodePtr head;  // head of linked list, or NULL if empty
    LinkedListNodePtr tail;  // tail of linked list, or NULL if empty
} *LinkedListPtr;

LinkedListPtr CreateLinkedList() {
    LinkedListPtr list;
    list = (LinkedListPtr)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListPtr));
    if (list == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: C# is not C. `list->head` would be a compiler error in C# because it's invalid syntax. In C# `NULL` is `null`, etc. I've removed the misused C# tag for you.

Comment: Can you post some [mcve]?

Comment: The return type of function `CreateLinkedListNode` is a pointer, but in that function you define `newNode` as a variable type `LinkedListNodePtr`, not a pointer.

Comment: I defined LInkedListNodePtr as LinkedListNode* in my struct definition

Comment: @JaewooCho, what value did you get when you try to add 5 in linked list?

Comment: @kuro -1099932976

Comment: when i put this code to debug,  printf("%d\n", newNode->data); after list->head = newNode, it's printing 5, but after list->tail = newNode, it prints memory location

Comment: @JaewooCho, can you show the code of `CreateLinkedList()`?

Comment: @kuro it's updated on my post!

Comment: @JaewooCho, not `CreateLinkedListNode()` but `CreateLinkedList()`

Comment: @kuro oh it's updated now sorry

Comment: @JaewooCho please show a [mcve]. The __exact__ code you compile.

Comment: @JaewooCho, `list = (LinkedListPtr)malloc(sizeof(LinkedListPtr));` shouldn't the `sizeof()` be `LinkedList` instead of `LinkedListPtr`

Comment: @kuro oh yeah it's working now, could you explain why it has to be sizeof(ptr)??

Comment: You are allocating a memory of size of a pointer. But you are trying to write beyond the allocated address which is undefined behavior

Comment: A short [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) may help identify some of the places where you are encountering problems. You are correctly using a list-struct that provides the `head` and `tail` pointers, you are just having an issue understanding how they work together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you do not initialize the `prev` and `next` members to `NULL` in `CreateLinkedListNode()`.
- the allocation size is incorrect in `CreateLinkedList()`: you should use:

  LinkedList *list = malloc(sizeof(*list));

and you should initialize the members `num_elements` to `0` and `head` and `tail` to `NULL`.

- the order of definitions is inadequate and the header files are missing.
- `AppendLinkedList()` does not update `num_elements`.

More generally, hiding pointers behind typedefs is error prone. The code is much more readable with the explicit pointer syntax.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ll_node {
    int data;                // Data this node holds 
    struct ll_node *next;    // next node in list, or NULL
    struct ll_node *prev;    // prev node in list, or NULL
} LinkedListNode;

typedef struct ll_head {
    uint64_t num_elements;   // # elements in the list
    LinkedListNode *head;    // head of linked list, or NULL if empty
    LinkedListNode *tail;    // tail of linked list, or NULL if empty
} LinkedList;

LinkedList *CreateLinkedList() {
    LinkedList *list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    if (list != NULL) {
        list->num_elements = 0;
        list->head = NULL;
        list->tail = NULL;
    }
    return list;
} 

LinkedListNode *CreateLinkedListNode(int data) {
    LinkedListNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
    if (newNode != NULL) {
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->prev = NULL;
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    return newNode;
}

int AppendLinkedList(LinkedList *list, int value) {
    if (list == NULL)
        return -1;

    LinkedListNode *newNode = CreateLinkedListNode(value);
    if (newNode == NULL)
        return -1;

    if (list->head == NULL) {
        list->head = newNode;
    } else {
        LinkedListNode *tail = list->tail;
        newNode->prev = tail;
        tail->next = newNode;
    }
    list->tail = newNode;
    list->num_elements += 1;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    LinkedList *list = CreateLinkedList();
    int data = 5;
    AppendLinkedList(list, data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed and thorough answer !!!!